# Running a BASH command on a file located on the Puppet server and not the client

Tags: bash, puppet, selinux

I'm trying to find a way to run a command on a SELinux .te file that is located on the puppet server, but not the client (I use the puppet-selinux module from puppetforge to compile the .te file into the .pp module file, so I don't need it on the client server).  My basic idea is something like:

```
class security::selinux_module {

  exec { 'selinux_module_check':
    command => "grep module selinux_module_source.te | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/;//' > /tmp/selinux_module_check.txt",
    source  => 'puppet:///modules/security/selinux_module_source.te',
  }
}
```

Though when trying to run it on the client server I get:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter source on Exec[selinux_module_check] at /etc/puppet/environments/master/security/manifests/selinux_module.pp:3 on node client.domain.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Puppet's `generate()` function to run commands on the master during catalog compilation and capture their output, but this is rarely a good thing to do, especially if the commands in question are expensive.  If you intend to transfer the resulting output to the client for some kind of use there, then you also need to pay careful attention to ensuring that it is appropriate for the client, which might not be the case if the client differs too much from the server.

> I'm trying to find a way to run a command on a SELinux .te file that is located on the puppet server, but not the client (I use the puppet-selinux module from puppetforge to compile the .te file into the .pp module file, so I don't need it on the client server

The simplest approach would be to run the needed command *directly*, once for all, from an interactive shell, and to put the result in a file from which the agent can obtain it, via Puppet or otherwise.  Only if the type enforcement file were dynamically generated would it make any sense to compile it every time you build a catalog.

I suggest, however, that you build a package (RPM, DEB, whatever) containing the selinux policy file and any needed installation scripts.  Put that package in your local repository, and manage it via a `Package` resource.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that if you are trying to do anything on the master during catalog compilation that functions are pretty much the way to go. Unsure if mentioning the issues with the attempt at using `source` with `exec` and using non-absolute executables in `exec`.